# Mutual recursion analysis

Tags: algorithm, performance, big-o

I'm trying to analyze these functions but i am getting a bit lost. So for function f when `t(n) = c` if `n < 1^-5`

so if `n >= 1^5` i get `t(n) = c2 + t( n / 2 ) + t2( n / 2)` where t2 is the time analysis of function h, but i'm confused on expanding it should it be something like

`t(n) = ( t(n / 2) + t2( n / 2) ) * c2 + c`

or should i be expanding t2 in side of that?

here is the code i am trying to analyze.

```
float f( float x) {
    if ( abs( x ) < 1e-5 ) {
        return x + ( ( x * x * x ) / 2 );
    }
    float y = f( x / 2 );
    float z = g( x / 2 );
    return 2 * y * z;
}

float g( float x ) {
    if ( abs( x ) < 1e-5 ) {
        return 1 + ( ( x * x ) / 2 );
    }
    float y = f( x / 2 );
    float z = g( x / 2 );
    return ( z * z ) + ( y * y );
}
```

Comment: Do you know the answer? It seems O(n) to me.

Comment: That is what i thought but i don't know for sure

Answer (score 2):

T<sub>1</sub>(n) = T<sub>1</sub>(n / 2) + T<sub>2</sub>(n / 2) + c1

T<sub>2</sub>(n) = T<sub>1</sub>(n / 2)+T<sub>2</sub>(n / 2) + c2

so we have

- T<sub>1</sub>(n) = O(T<sub>2</sub>(n))
- T<sub>1</sub>(n) = 2T<sub>1</sub>(n / 2) + c1

since c1 = O(n<sup>log<sub>2</sub>2</sup>) master theorem implies that

```
T(n) = O(n)
```

Comment: Nice and simple explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Even though we are calling two different functions in this code, there is a thing about them that makes finding the complexity of this recursion easy.

What's happening is that at the top level, if you are entering `f()`, you are evaluating `x` and then calling two different functions - itself and `g()`. Even if you enter the function `g()` first, same thing happens, i.e. `g()` calls itself and `f()`.

Since, every level down the tree the value of x halves, the number of levels on this tree would be *Log<sub>2</sub>(n)*. Also, every node has 2 children viz. f(x/2) and g(x/2).

This is a complete binary tree of length Log<sub>2</sub>(n).

Work done on each node is constant - If the node represents the call to `f()`, you do `2 * y * z`, which is constant. If the node represents the call to `g()`, you do `y*y + z*z`, which is also constant.

Hence, all we need to do is, find the total number of nodes in a compete binary tree of length Log<sub>2</sub>(n) and we have our complexity.

- A perfect binary tree of height *h* has total 2<sup>h + 1</sup> - 1 nodes.
- In this case it would be 2<sup>Log<sub>2</sub>(n) + 1</sup> - 1 nodes.
- Also, a<sup>Log<sub>a</sub>b</sup> = b (By [property of logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Canceling_exponentials))<sup>*1*</sup>
- Hence, the complexity is O(2<sup>Log<sub>2</sub>(n)</sup>) = O(n).

---

<sup><sup>*1*</sup> *See first property in "Cancelling Exponentials" section.*</sup>